# I cant refrence the adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an adaptor that I initiate in onCreate and a listview that I initiate in onViewCreated
I'm trying to setAdapter but I can't pass the adapter in onViewCreated.
Ive tried multiple things like moving them from onCreate in onViewCreated but it seems that the app crashes if I initialize the adapter anywhere else and I cant use findViewById anywhere but in onViewCreated

```
class Istoric : Fragment() {
    var array= arrayOf("item1","item2")



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(MainActivity(),R.layout.listview_item,array)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_istoric, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val lv1: ListView = view.findViewById(R.id.lv)
        lv1.setAdapter(adapter)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `adapter` object is a local variable to `onCreate(...)` so it cannot be accessed elsewhere. You can move it to a class variable like this:

```kotlin
class Istoric : Fragment() {
    var array= arrayOf("item1","item2")

    private lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.listview_item, array)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_istoric, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val lv1: ListView = view.findViewById(R.id.lv)
        lv1.setAdapter(adapter)
    }
}
```

I also added the `requireContext()` call to your `ArrayAdapter` constructor since you don't want to create a new instance of your `MainActivity` there.